# Highcharts draggable columns and set value by click

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, angular5

I want to make my chart, with the option of setting the value after clicking and draggable. Draggable works but the event with a click complicates the matter because draggable then goes crazy because it removes the point before moving.

My event code. There i try to first remove existing point next add new value

```
events: {
          click: function (e) {
            // find the clicked values and the series
            let x = Math.round(e.xAxis[0].value),
              y = Math.round(e.yAxis[0].value),
              series = this.series[0];

            console.log("values",x,y,series);

            // Add it
            if(e.yAxis[0].value <= 16){
              series.data[x].remove();
              series.addPoint([x, y]);

            }
          }
        }
```

And draggable is from plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this:

```
events: {
          click: function (e) {
            // find the clicked values and the series
            let x = Math.round(e.xAxis[0].value),
              y = Math.round(e.yAxis[0].value),
              series = this.series[0];

            console.log("values",x,y,series);

            // Add it
            if(e.yAxis[0].value <= 16){
              series.data[x].update(y);

            }
          }
        }
```